# How to attach metadata to a view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way to attach some data (e.g. an NSString) to a UIView? (something like `[view setMetadata:@"username"]`).

Let me explain what I need to achieve. I programatically create some UIButtons that will show a user's profile on touch. They will all trigger a method on touch, but when that method is called, I need to know which user should it go to. As a workaround, I can use an NSDictionary where the keys are numbers, and set the view tags to match those numbers, but I wonder if there's a better way that this.

Comment: Subclass `UIView`, then add the properties you need?

Comment: @dandan78 you should write this as a proper answer because it's good advice, and if nothing better than this shows up I'll accept it.

Comment: What you are doing is a good approach. The `UIView` framework doesn't support associating an arbitrary pointer with a view. Using the tag as you are is fine.

Comment: @GabiPurcaru Subclassing `UIView` won't help. `UIButton` won't be a subclass of your custom view class. And neither will lots of other view classes.

Comment: @maddy that's right, but I can subclass `UIButton` because I'm pretty sure at this point that it's the only view that I want to have this functionality. You should both write these as answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had I read your question more carefully, I would have recommended subclassing `UIButton` instead of `UIView`. At any rate, the principle is the same: subclass, then add required properties and where necessary, such as in the `action:` method, cast to your subclass and retrieve the data.

Since we're already discussing subclassing, you could actually add the `setMetadata:` method from your example and use it to store an `id` or `NSDictionary` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a tag to a view.  The tag is just a number so you wouldn't be able to use it for strings.  You could have an NSDictionary with the string data key'd from the number you use as the tag.

Comment: You can simplify this by using `UIView` objects as keys for the dictionary. This way you don't need to worry about tags at all.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, there's one more approach. You can add properties to a class by using a category and the `objc_setAssociatedObject` function. See, for example, [this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/iphone-development/how-to-add-a-property-via-class-category/).

I personally prefer [Stephen Johnson's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20550151/2911458).

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions you've been given are fine ways to accomplish what you'd like to accomplish, but keep one thing in mind: in iOS you're most often following the [MVC design pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html). In MVC, views are normally "dumb" objects that are simply responsible for displaying whatever information you give them*.

Because of this, you may want to redesign your solution so that the information isn't held by the view, but rather is held by the controller that knows about your views and your model. It does sometimes seem like an unnecessary step, but there are good reasons for the separation that will become more and more obvious the larger your application gets.

*Note that the exception to that rule are input views that take information from the user, but even in those cases the controller queries those views for their information.